# DetachedCriteria equivalent needed

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I need the DetachedCriteria equivalent to the following HQL:

```
select obj
from Objects obj, Text text
where obj.TextId = text.TextId and <Some_Other_Condition>
order by text.Value
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all depending of your Mapped objects

Here is an example:

```
    var criteriaObject = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Objects))
        .CreateAlias("TextReference", "text")
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Activate", true))
        .AddOrder(new Order("text.Value", true));
```

Hope it helps